# What is the best way to update the Solana CLI?

Tags: cli, solana-cli

I understand that we can just install following the commands here: https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools

But is there a way to install Solana CLI where it is easily updatable in the future as the Solana CLI updates with a simple apt update/upgrade?

When the Solana CLI updates, how would we update it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you already have the Solana CLI installed on your system, you can quickly update to the latest version using the CLI itself.

To update, run the update command:

```
solana-install update
```

This will auto download and update your local CLI to the correct "channel version" you have selected.

Your channel version is likely set to "stable" by default when you install the Solana CLI. So when you run the update command, it will look for a newer "stable" version (aka the version that is tagged with the "stable" tag on the GitHub repo aka the mainnet version)

If you want to easily update to a different channel version (e.g. `stable`, `beta`, and `edge`), you can update your install config.yml file and change your desired channel version.

To do this, open your config file like so:

```
nano ~/.config/solana/install/config.yml
```

And update the config declaration for `explicit_release`, changing the last part to `edge`, `beta`, or `stable`:

```
explicit_release: !Channel edge
```

Answer (score 0):

> After a successful install, **solana-install update** may be used to
> easily update the Solana software to a newer version at any time.